# C# richtextbox track new text

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I would like to keep track of the text that has been written in a richtextbox.
If user ONE writes "Hello World!" then user TWO edits this by adding the word "Hello" so the new sentence is "Hello Hello World!". Now I need to know where user TWO added this.

This data has been writen to a database. So I thought i could just check what differs from the already stored text and then I could assume evrything else belongs to user TWO. This worked as long as they don't write the same letters at the same spot.

Any ide where to start?

Comment: Sounds like you want a history table?

Comment: What you want is called SignalR. Then you can track the users data separately in real time but still display it together and allow for a single place that can be updated by the users.

Comment: I think i solved it by tracking key press and then create a sort of map that maps each letter position to a user.